# How to compress and cache files with IIS when filename is determined by ASP.NET Web API controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iis-8.5

I have a ASP.NET Web API with the following controller action for serving possibly large (<1-200MB) 3D models which are stored in JSON format somewhere on disk (outside the web root):

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetModel(Guid accessToken, Guid modelId)
{
    Guid projectId = MyBackend.Validate(accessToken);
    string fileName = MyPaths.GetModelFile(projectId, modelId);

    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StringContent(File.ReadAllText(fileName),
                                         Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    return response;
}
```

In my Global.asax I have this line:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Insert(
        0, new ServerCompressionHandler(new GZipCompressor(), new DeflateCompressor()));
```

When I call the API endpoint, the content is gzipped as expected, but IIS (8.5) doesn't cache the compressed results, so it has to re-compress the relevant file for every request. I expect it's not cached because the controller reads the JSON into memory and serves it as `StringContent`.

I know next to nothing about IIS and little about ASP.NET Web API. How can I best serve the JSON files so that they are compressed AND make sure that IIS caches the compressed results, so that they won't have to be re-compressed every time? (And if this sounds like a bad idea for some reason, what should I rather be doing?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating a cache you have full control over it, instead of delegating compression to IIS or, in this case, Web API message handlers. It's the best way to optimize CPU usage sacrificing disk space.

Create a directory on your server and save there temporary files with the compressed content. Then, in your API request, check if the compressed file for your 3D model is already created. If not, create it on the fly, and store it on disk. The next time the model is requested the result will already be calculated and you will only need to return the compressed file contents.

```
// Calculate a path for your cache file.
var compressedCacheFilename = GetCachePath(filename);
Stream compressedStream;
if (File.Exists(compressedCacheFilename)) {
    compressedStream = new FileStream(compressedCacheFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
}
else {
    /* Use the best compression algorithm for your data
       and store it to the corresponding path. */
    compressedStream = compressor.CompressTo(
        new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
        compressedCacheFilename
    );
}

HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StreamContent(compressedStream);
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Clear();
response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("gzip"); // your compression algorithm
```

Notice that in the code example, I'm using `StreamContent` instead of `StringContent` because the first uses less memory. It's also important to know that this assumes models are not going to change. It'll be also likely you need a maximum capacity on disk for this.